Uncaught (in promise) Error: getFocusedTabInfo() - Failed to get tabInfo for focused tab
I need to perform an action when a tab on the lightning console app closes. I am trying the following logic provided in Salesforce documentation but all I am getting is the

Error: getFocusedTabInfo() - Failed to get tabInfo for focused tab.

Logic that I am trying :
import { IsConsoleNavigation, getFocusedTabInfo, closeTab } from 'lightning/platformWorkspaceApi';

export default class ABC extends LightningElement {
@wire(IsConsoleNavigation) isConsoleNavigation;

    async closeTab() {
        console.log('Inside closeTab');
        if (!this.isConsoleNavigation) {
            return;
        }
        const { tabId } = await getFocusedTabInfo();
        console.log('tabId == '+tabId);
        await closeTab(tabId);
    }
}

Any help would be great. Thanks!

Thanks for your question. To help us help you, would you be able to also add some details about where the component is being hosted, and what behaviour your are expecting? How are you expecting to get tab info if it has already been closed?

I have referred to this documentation and implemented the code into my org. I have added this component to the record page and When I click on the button to close the tab I get the tab ID in the browser console. You can refer to the screenshot and video for the same.
HTML:
<template>
    <lightning-card title="WorkspaceAPICloseTab" icon-name="standard:scheduling_workspace">
        <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
            <lightning-button label="Close Focused Tab" onclick={closeTab}>
            </lightning-button>
        </div>
    </lightning-card>
</template>

JS:
import { LightningElement, wire } from 'lwc';
import { IsConsoleNavigation, getFocusedTabInfo, closeTab } from 'lightning/platformWorkspaceApi';

export default class ConsoleAppLWC extends LightningElement {
    @wire(IsConsoleNavigation) isConsoleNavigation;

    async closeTab() {
        if (!this.isConsoleNavigation) {
            return;
        }
        const { tabId } = await getFocusedTabInfo();
        console.log('tabId == '+tabId);
        await closeTab(tabId);
    }
}   

XML:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>60.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
    </targets>
</LightningComponentBundle>

Output:
Screenshot: 
Video: https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/video/30230091?key=358eadcaaea75d0075f170c270ed8ec7

Thanks Tushar for sharing the details, But I want to invoke the closeTab() function when a tab on console app closes not on click of custom button. I referred the same documentation but I am not able to capture the standard tab closure event.
